# lsof command not found during shell script execution in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell-script, shell, jenkins

I'm trying to get process id which is running against specific port hence manually following command successfully executed -

```
lsof -i :9090 -t
```

But if I run same code on same machine through shell script of Jenkins pipeline, it results into an error - `lsof: command not found`

Below is code from Jenkins pipeline -

```
def stopServer() {
    script {
        echo "Stopping server"
        sh '''var=\$(lsof -i :9090 -t)
          kill -TERM \$var
          '''
    }
}
```

Please help to understand why same command working from same machine's terminal but not from Jenkins pipeline's shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be because `lsof` is not in a directory listed in `jenkins`' PATH environment variable.

The solution is to either:

1. make sure PATH is set correctly inside jenkins **or**
2. specify the full pathname to `lsof` in your `stopServer` def.

---

BTW, `lsof -i :9090 -t` doesn't just list the PIDs of local server processes **listening** on port 9090, it also lists the PIDs of any client processes connecting to port 9090 of any machine on the net.

You probably want to use `netstat -tpln` instead.  e.g.

```
netstat -tpln | awk -F'[[:space:]/:]+' '$5 == 9090 {print $(NF-2)}'
```

Comment: Thanks cas for detailed explanation! This helped to resolve my issue.